# How can I transform?

Tags: word-usage

Yesterday was so cold that we stayed indoors. 
Is it correct to rewrite this sentence as:

> It was such a cold day yesterday that we stayed indoors.

I'm not sure about the usage "a cold day yesterday".

Comment: Are you asking whether your second sentence is grammatical (in which case it is, though *indoor* should be *indoors*) or whether it is 'the correct transformation of your first sentence'? The latter is probably unanswerable, at least without a definition of "correct".

Comment: Thank you. I want to know which of "such a cold yesterday" and "such a cold day yesterday" is grammatical or if both are grammatical.

Comment: _Such a cold yesterday_ is certainly not idiomatic; I am dubious whether to regard it as even grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Either sentence is fine. It just depends on where you want to put the emphasis.

If the emphasis is on "yesterday," I would use the sentence that begins with this word. If the emphasis is on how cold it was, I would use the sentence that opens with this.

Answer (score 0):

It was so cold yesterday; Yesterday was so cold, It was such a cold day yesterday; but NOT such a cold yesterday.

I had such a cold (meaning illness) yesterday is a different thing.